# SAP Cloud SDK SoapRequest Timeout After 60s

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

Issue: SAP Cloud SDK SoapRequest timeout after 60s
Reproduce issue:

1. Adopt SAP Cloud SDK version: 5.1.0 with jdk17
2. Configure destination with adding two parameters:
   HTML5.ConnectionTimeoutInSeconds=120
   HTML5.SocketReadTimeoutInSeconds=300
3. Using connectivity service and destination service to consume on-premise SAP SOAP API
4. Error log:

   STDOUT Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Read timed out
   STDOUT at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430) ~[axis2-kernel-1.7.9.jar:1.7.9]
   STDOUT at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.impl.httpclient4.HTTPSenderImpl.sendViaPost(HTTPSenderImpl.java:242) ~[axis2-transport-http-1.7.9.jar:1.7.9]
   STDOUT at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:121) ~[axis2-transport-http-1.7.9.jar:1.7.9]
   STDOUT at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:403) ~[axis2-transport-http-1.7.9.jar:1.7.9]
   STDOUT at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:234) ~[axis2-transport-http-1.7.9.jar:1.7.9]
   STDOUT at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:431) ~[axis2-kernel-1.7.9.jar:1.7.9]
   STDOUT at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:399) ~[axis2-kernel-1.7.9.jar:1.7.9]
   STDOUT at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225) ~[axis2-kernel-1.7.9.jar:1.7.9]
   STDOUT at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:150) ~[axis2-kernel-1.7.9.jar:1.7.9]
   STDOUT at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.soapclient.QCD_011_SALESORDERMAStub.simulateSalesOrder(QCD_011_SALESORDERMAStub.java:524) ~[classes/:na]
   STDOUT at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.controllers.ToolController.lambda$testOrderSimulation$504d6b90$1(ToolController.java:140) ~[classes/:na]
   STDOUT at com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.connectivity.soap.SoapRequest.execute(SoapRequest.java:442) ~[soap-5.1.0.jar:na]
5. Detailed logs

   STDOUT java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
   STDOUT at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedRead(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
   STDOUT at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
   STDOUT at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
   STDOUT at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
   STDOUT at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
   STDOUT at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:161) ~[httpcore-4.4.16.jar:4.4.16]
   STDOUT at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:82) ~[httpcore-4.4.16.jar:4.4.16]
   STDOUT at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:276) ~[httpcore-4.4.16.jar:4.4.16]
   STDOUT at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138) ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]
   STDOUT at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]
   STDOUT at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259) ~[httpcore-4.4.16.jar:4.4.16]
   STDOUT at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:294) ~[httpcore-4.4.16.jar:4.4.16]
   STDOUT at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:257) ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]
   STDOUT at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:207) ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]
   STDOUT at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273) ~[httpcore-4.4.16.jar:4.4.16]
   STDOUT at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125) ~[httpcore-4.4.16.jar:4.4.16]
   STDOUT at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:679) ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]
   STDOUT at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:481) ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]
   STDOUT at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]
   STDOUT at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72) ~[httpclient-4.5.14.jar:4.5.14]
   STDOUT at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.impl.httpclient4.HTTPSenderImpl.executeMethod(HTTPSenderImpl.java:873) ~[axis2-transport-http-1.7.9.jar:1.7.9]
   STDOUT at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.impl.httpclient4.HTTPSenderImpl.sendViaPost(HTTPSenderImpl.java:238) ~[axis2-transport-http-1.7.9.jar:1.7.9]
   STDOUT at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:121) ~[axis2-transport-http-1.7.9.jar:1.7.9]
   STDOUT at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:403) ~[axis2-transport-http-1.7.9.jar:1.7.9]
   STDOUT at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:234) ~[axis2-transport-http-1.7.9.jar:1.7.9]
   STDOUT at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:431) ~[axis2-kernel-1.7.9.jar:1.7.9]
   STDOUT at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:399) ~[axis2-kernel-1.7.9.jar:1.7.9]
   STDOUT at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225) ~[axis2-kernel-1.7.9.jar:1.7.9]
   STDOUT at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:150) ~[axis2-kernel-1.7.9.jar:1.7.9]

Answer (score 2):

The [SAP Cloud SDK for Java](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/overview-cloud-sdk-for-java) does neither evaluate the `HTML5.ConnectionTimeoutInSeconds` nor the `HTML5.SocketReadTimeoutInSeconds` destination properties.

As far as I can tell (according to [SAP Note 2680207](https://me.sap.com/notes/2680207)), these properties are specific to the [SAP Approuter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sap/approuter) when being deployed within the SAP Neo cloudplatform.

Nevertheless, the SAP Cloud SDK offers some [configuration APIs](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/connectivity/http-client#configuring-the-clients) for applications to tune the HTTP client creation - including a connection timeout.
These timeouts, however, are **shared** for all HTTP clients (i.e. independent of the destination configuration).